# 504 Gateway Time out in ASP.NET MVC while file downloading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-504

A couple of users are getting **504 Gateway Time out** error when they are trying to download a file from our website. This time out error comes after exactly 2 minutes of time. If the user can download the file before 2 minutes then it is working fine. I have checked my local machine to put Thread.Sleep to more than 2 minutes but it is also working fine.

Not sure if it is IIS or Server issue. Can anyone please help me and a possible solution or suggestion to this?

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score -2):

I belief it's a IIS or Server issue. Better to communicate with the IIS or system adminstrator. Please follow the below link for more details on that issue.

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E504.html

Thanks

Comment: Please avoid answers merely pointing to a link. You should describe the relevant part in your answer.